# UIButton Title Doesn't Appear unless Clicked

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I don't know how to describe the problem other than the title of the question: I have a button with title that appears when it's clicked, but not in its normal state. I've looked around everywhere to no avail.

If you need to see specific code or want other details (as I'm sure you will) just let me know.

EDIT: The button is created in a nib, but here is the code that sets the title and also deals with a subview of the button.

```
[chapterButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %d",newBookName,newChapter] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImageView *triunghiView = (UIImageView *) [chapterButton viewWithTag:kTagTriangleView];
if(!triunghiView)
{
    triunghiView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"triunghi.png"]] autorelease];
    [triunghiView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    [triunghiView setTag:kTagTriangleView];
    [triunghiView sizeToFit];
    [chapterButton addSubview:triunghiView];

}

[triunghiView setCenter:CGPointMake(chapterButton.titleLabel.frame.origin.x + chapterButton.titleLabel.frame.size.width + triunghiView.frame.size.width + 5, chapterButton.frame.size.height/2)];
```

Comment: Is it that if nobody will ask,you won't show the code?? Its an obvious thing that you must show the code.

Comment: Can you show us the code there the button is initialized? Or this button is created inside of a .nib file?

Comment: Sarah I wasn't sure which part of the code you would like to see. So better to ask first. :)

Comment: Maxim: the button is part of a nib file. I can show you the code related to setting the title and a subview of this button. See expanded question.

Comment: And look Sarah borrrden solved the problem without any code. Not so obvious anymore huh ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem recently, you have to also set the **title color** of your button, or else it will turn white and appear invisible (in the default setup of round rect button).

`[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

However, it could also likely be Kjuly's answer!  Without code it is hard to tell.

Comment: Oh my goodness I can't believe it was this simple. My button is black so I just changed the title to whiteColor. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No code, well, guess you might set a wrong state for your title.

```
[yourButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```